# parameter value changes suddenly

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, electron, fs

I've been create an electron app using node and i have faced with an unexpected wrong
I don't Have any idea about this:

this is Object that i passed:

```
{
  lessons: [
        name: "math",
        scores: [90, 96, 76],
        isEmpty: false
      ]
}
```

and this is another file that my modules there:

```
const fs = require('fs'),
  path = require("path");

class File {
  static save(data) {
    ///////////// Here "data" is the expected Object **********************
    fs.exists(path.join(__dirname, '../data/lessons.json'), isExist => {
      if (isExist) {
        //////////// Here "data" is this    {lesson: []} ********************** 
        const prev = require('../data/lessons.json');
        // Write New Data in Prevoius Data
        prev.lessons.push(data.lessons[0]);
        fs.writeFile(
          path.join(__dirname, '../data/lessons.json'),
          JSON.stringify(prev),
          err => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              console.error('\nCan not Save New Data\n');
            }
          }
        );
      } else {
        const json = JSON.stringify(data);
        fs.writeFile(
          path.join(__dirname, '../data/lessons.json'),
          json,
          err => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              console.error('\nCan not Save Data\n');
            }
          }
        );
      }
    });
    data.lessons = [];
  }

}
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

USE:

```
{
  lessons: {
        name: "math",
        scores: [90, 96, 76],
        isEmpty: false
         }
}
```

OR

```
[
  lessons: {
        name: "math",
        scores: [90, 96, 76],
        isEmpty: false
      }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for evry one who wants to solve my problem **my problem is in last line of code when i
wants to clear data from data.lesson Object i should put that on if and else.....**